# Algorithm to construct similarity structure from hash lookup table

Tags: algorithms, graphs, named-entity-recognition

I have constructed a lookup table using locality-sensitive hashing for comparing nearly similar documents/records. If two records (columns) have the same hash value in a row, they are considered to be similar. For example, the structure is

```
   R1 R2 R3 R4 R5
b1 a1 a2 a3 a2 a5 .....
b2 a2 a4 a1 a4 a4 ..... 
b3 a3 a5 a3 a7 a4....
```

Since each band holds similar records, similar record sets will be

```
S1 = {R2,R4}
S2 = {R2, R4, R5}
S3 = {R1,R3}
```

And the merged similarity structures will be

```
S1' = {R2,R4,R5}
S2' = {R1,R3}
```

I want to span the matrix and map all similarity structures so I have buckets of similar records. The dimensionality of the hash table is large, hence a naive approach is not likely to work. What types of algorithms should I consider to achieve this efficiently?

Edit 1:
Question updated to clarify more on the objective

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. You already have a mapping from docs to hash buckets. You just want smaller buckets? use more buckets.

Comment: Apologize about missing details, added more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithm you are asking about is very straightforward.

What you do, you are looking for [connected components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_%28graph_theory%29) in a certain graph where edges are determined by matching hash values. You can implement this with a modification of the [disjoint-set data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure).

Your particular variation would be that apart from keeping track of vertices in each component, you have to keep track of m (number of rows) sets of hash values that have been found for each component.